# I have duplicate proceed to checkout buttons, how to disable one with css

Tags: button, duplicates, checkout, wordpress-theme-astra

Two buttons appear on the checkout page with the same function (proceed to checkout). The error is in the Astra theme for Elementor, I changed the theme and the second button disappeared. I need to know how to remove the second button through css. I use wordpress.com

I modified the builder theme and it was resolved. but I don't want to change the theme, I want to disable a button through css.